# Struts2 - Converting struts xml to annotation

Tags: struts2

I have defined the type=steam, but its throwing error for below annotation.

```
@Result(name="success",type="stream" ,params={"contentType","text/html","inputName","inputStream"}).
```

**struts.xml**

```
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
 <action name="getJSON" class="com.Action" method="list">    
<result type="stream">
  <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
  <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
</result>
</action>
</package>
```

How to define action name and method in annotation ?

Already i have one annotation, so i have added results ..

```
 @Results({@Result(name=com.action.Part.INPUT, value="/search.jsp",
 type= ServletDispatcherResult.class, params={"location", "/search.jsp"  }),
 @Result(name = ActionSupport.SUCCESS,type="stream",params= {"contentType","text/html","inputName","inputStream"})})
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to tell us what the error is?

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Class<? extends Result>

Comment: So, what in the annotation represents a class, maybe the result type?

Comment: In annotation class has multiple methods like actions, so when execute action list return type success, need to work above result annotation.

Comment: @user2480430 There's not such type success, there's a type "stream' and there's a name "success" the last is optional.

Comment: I have added result annotation with @Results..Have updated question.

Comment: @user2480430 type attribute should be a string not a class.

Comment: This is already i have annotation which is working fine.No issues..@Result(name=com.action.Part.INPUT, value="/search.jsp",
 type= ServletDispatcherResult.class, params={"location", "/search.jsp"  }) Now i'm adding @Result(name="success",type="stream" ,params={"contentType","text/html","inputName","inputStream"}) into @Results, so getting error in steam.

Answer (score 0):

Because have imported import org.apache.struts2.config.Result; instead of import org.apache.struts2.convension.annotation.Result